# What is a very general term or phrase for a course that is not online?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm trying to find the most general term or phrase for the opposite of "online course". When a course is not online, but in a classroom, or anywhere else people interact in the same place, not through a computer, how would I call it?

I'm translating some words used in messages and labels in a e-learning web application used by companies. So, I'm trying to find the right answer for a course, instead of online, took in a classroom or any corporate environment. I choose "Face-to-Face", but don't know if it's the best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are a number of ways to say this. I'm not sure which is the most common or conventional though.

1. In-person class/course
2. On-campus class/course
3. Traditional class/course
4. Offline class/course
5. In-class course

4 seems might seem like an obvious opposite, but it sounds a little silly to me. I personally would use 2. If for some reason the place where the classes are held is not called a "campus", then my next choice would be 1.

---

Edit: Face-to-face might work depending on the context. It might not be the best option though because instructions and lessons can be given face-to-face via Skype, for example.

---

Edit: Upon reconsideration, using face-to-face for Skype lessons does seem like a stretch. There were lots of accurate hits on Google for [face-to-face classes](https://www.google.com/search?q=face-to-fece+classes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=face-to-face+classes) meaning a class taken in a classroom.

Comment: “Offline” is common in contexts where online is the norm.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no hypernym for "classes which are not online".

You could qualify such classes as "on-site" or "physical"; but except in a context where online and non-online have already been clearly distinguished this is going to read/sound rather clunky. What you're asking for is a term to "mark" an "unmarked" category, which is usually going to be awkward.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, **face-to-face** classes is the term used for these classes.

Other terms I’ve seen used include: *resident, on-campus, classroom,* and even *traditional*. There are used adjectively, in phrases such as: *resident sections, on-campus classes, classroom environment, traditional courses*, etc.

[This Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=face+to+face+vs+online+learning) shows many examples of *face-to-face* being used to describe classes traditional classroom courses that are not online.

Another term used in educational circles nowadays is [**blended learning**](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20a%20blended%20course). A blended course meets face-to-face but is supplemented with online components.

Comment: You can also use the words "venue"
or
"instructor-led"

Answer (score 1):

1. on-site classes
2. in-campus classes
3. in-class courses

'Offline' is definitely not the answer. It has a different meaning all together --- when not connected (to the www, etc.)

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can edit your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article How to Answer.

Answer (score 0):

those institutions that present both types (like Manhattan prep, Kaplan, ...) use "In-class"

Answer (score 0):

I have heard "in-seat" to describe a class that is not "on-line".

Answer (score 0):

You can teach REMOTELY (ONLINE) or IN PERSON.  IN PERSON would be my choice.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. This site encourages its users to do research before they answer and provide links where they found the information they are giving. Personal choices are off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer]. Your answer has been flagged as low quality and might be removed.