# What would be the best phrase for meeting on-site (in contrast to remote / web meetings)?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

As far as I see there are several phrases possible:

"We want to ..."

- "meet in person"
- "meet on site" / "meet on-site"
- "meet locally"
- "meet physically"
- "meet face-to-face"

Is there a difference in the meaning? When should I use which phrase?

Comment: Meeting in person, locally, physically, or face-to-face could be on-site or off-site (but still in person). If you mean on-site, use on-site.

Comment: Related question: [The opposite of online course](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/131242/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-site would normally refer to a work site. Locally would be right if you live near each other and choose a nearby place to meet. If you are a long way from each other it can't be local for both of you.

The other three are all correct for physical meetings in an unspecified place.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that "on-site" normally refers to a work site. And is it written "on-site" or "on site" in this context?

Comment: I think I would use on-site meeting when I meet on-site, but I think either alternative is acceptable in either position.  Some even make it a single word. If you check the meaning via google you will see that it doesn't actually mean a work site, but that is usually what it is in practice.